# How to Manage Qty Website / Store wise in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am working on magento2, I am facing problem in to manage product qty in store / website wise, the scenario is:

I have created 6 websites/stores in magento (area wise), and select the same root category in it.all the websites have same products (websites names are added in product), how does I manage product qty seperately store wise.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You go to Magento admin and then open Catalog->Products. Open one product, then you can see the lift side Store View, click on this dropdown and select that store there you need to change your product qty.

Comment: the qty sets globally, If I change from 1 store magento change from all store.

Comment: like: we have 1 product Milk 1 liter and we have three stores, when chen i change fron 1 store it will apply rest of the 2 stores, this is the isue

Comment: Update the Quantity:
Scroll down to the "Advanced Inventory" section, and update the "Qty" (quantity) field with the desired quantity for the selected store view.  After that clear cache

Comment: Problem is that, the qty in magento is global by default, i want to set it website or store,

Answer (score 0):

Firstly **Go to Store->inventory->sources and create individual source for each and every website**
than **go to store->inventory->stocks and assign sources to stock**

After that you can manage quantity by Website or store..

**Do let me know if you're facing any queries yet..**